# Differences on delphi code execution under WinXP and Win7. Why?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-xe

The following piece of delphi code compiled with DelphiXE under Windows 7 is running differently on a Windows XP system. 
In a form we have a procedure handling user response on VK_Fxx keys.

```
procedure TfrmGA010.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
inherited;
KillKey := False;

if bvMF1Panel.Enabled then
begin
case Key of
     VK_F3  : begin
                ...........
                key := 0;
                KillKey := True;
                exit;
              end;
     VK_F4  : begin
                ............
                key := 0;
                KillKey := True;
                exit;
              end;
     VK_F5  : begin
                ...........
                key := 0;
                KillKey := True;
                exit;
              end;
     VK_F7  : begin
                .......
                key := 0;
                KillKey := True;
                exit;
              end;
     VK_F8  : begin
                ........
                key := 0;
                KillKey := True;
                exit;
              end;
    VK_F11  : begin
                if YesNoMsg('Delete?') then
                begin
                  ..........
                  **F5.Click;**               
                end;
                exit;
              end;
  end;
end;
```

Line code **F5.Click** is executed under Windows XP but not under Windows 7 where is skipped over and program continues with next step. Any help please?

Comment: @Bakas George, can you please give the complete code of the VK_F11 block.

Comment: @Gamecat, the missing code line in VK_F11 block just calls a firebird stored procedure to delete few records.

Comment: And if you comment out these lines it still doesn't work? But the YesNoMsg line is executed? There might be an exception in the missing lines...

Comment: Your problem is not in this code. This executes the same on XP as Windows 7.

Comment: So you compiled it in Win7 and shipped it to the XP machine even though it didn't work on your development machine? Are you stepping **into** the code in both environments, or is one of your apples actually an orange? And what happened to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696389/child-form-positioning-like-statusbar ?

Comment: Sounds like something is intercepting and consuming the F5 hotkey, on that PARTICULAR XP SYSTEM, and that if you went and set up a CLEAN XP VM, which all software developers should do, you would find that it's not XP, it's YOUR particular XP BOX.

Comment: After a lot of debugging i found that the problem on Windows 7 must be the MessageDlg which is behind the YesNoMsg function - MessageDlg(Msg,mtConfirmation,[mbNO,mbYES],0). Compilation runs ok on any XP Box but not on Win-7. ??? @Warren P

Comment: You have been bitten by the famous Z-Order bug.

Answer (score 3):

Basic diagnostics would involve putting the suspect code in a try except block with a basic ShowMessage in the exception handler.

```
try
  if YesNoMsg('Delete?') then
    begin
      ..........
      **F5.Click;**               
    end;
except
  on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage(E.ClassName + #13#10 + E.Message);
end;
```

If you don't like ShowMessage, you could always have a TMemo on your form that you can append text to

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('2 records deleted successfully, about to click F5 :-) ');
```

Also, defensive programming would suggest you check the result of previous line of code before continuing on to the next instruction (especially if it's a sub-routine that deletes a couple of records). You should turn it into a sub-routine that returns at least 2 different possible results, plus it's own exception handler (at least so you can put a breakpoint in it when you want to), not simply enclose it in a function that returns True at the end.

Also, I would move that F5.Click line into a procedure called DeleteSomething and call that instead.

If all else fails, log the living daylights out of it. When the debugger can't help, logging is the next best thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug the code and see if VK_FXX is the same  like the KEY.